# How do I treat a string attribute as a number when filtering

Tags: magento-1.9, module

When I'm trying to filter products I get weird results, I have created my own search box with the following index controller:

```
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('womble25');    
    $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=>'womble25','gt'=>$params['lbparam']),
    )); 
    $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=>'womble25','lt'=>$params['ubparam']),
    ));

    $search = "";
    foreach ($collection as $_product) {
        $search .= " - ".$_product->getName(). " (".$_product->getWomble25().") - <br>";
    }
```

I input lower as '1' and higher as '20' and get something like the following:

```
- product A (1132) - 
- product B (1719) - 
- product C (10456) - 
- product D (17025) - 
- product E (17.02) - 
- product F (1.171) -
```

Ofcourse I'm expecting only products with womble25 value between 1 and 20...

EDIT:

I found the issue, it is that the attribute womble25 is a string, which it needs to be as it is a value to 4 sf, ie. 0.2300 is valid and the 2 0's are required at the end, so my question is:

How do I treat a string attribute as a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out, just needed to change the type of the input to a float and it worked perfectly:

```
    $filter = array('from'=>(float)$params['lbparam'],'to'=>(float)$params['ubparam']);
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('womble25',array($filter));
```